# How to make function that validates first and last name input - Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I need to make a function that verifies if the user writes his first and last name. It receives a string and returns a boolean. It returns true if the string has 2 names(first and last) and the first letter of each name has to be capitalized. I´ve been trying to make it but havent been able to do it, if anyone could help me i´d apreciate it. btw i´m doing this in kotlin.

edit: I forgot to mention that i can´t use .split()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a code-writing service. Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please explain what you've tried and where you're stuck. It's fine to ask for help with homework, but this isn't a do-my-homework site.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry it seems that way, i was very close to getting it right, i just didn´t want to include my code because people would probably say it was weird. Someone already answered, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the string on spaces then check if the first letter is capitalized for each one:

```kotlin
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean {
    val names = name.split(' ')
    return names.size == 2 && names.all { it[0].isUpperCase() }
}
```

If you really can't use `split` or `indexOf` for some reason, then just use a loop:

```kotlin
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean {
    if (name.length == 0 || !name[0].isUpperCase()) {
        return false
    }
    var spaces = 0
    for (i in 0 until name.length) {
        if (name[i] == ' ') {
            spaces += 1
            if (spaces > 1 || !name[i + 1].isUpperCase()) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: That would work, but i forgot to mention that i can´t use .split() in my program. Thank you for responding eihter way.

Comment: @FGomes Can you use `indexOf`?

Comment: Unfortunately, also can´t

Comment: @FGomes I've edited my answer to include a version with a loop.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I was very close to that but i was doing it wrong, now i understand.